# crypto.lib(err.c.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

I am trying to integrate grpc with existing project. 
I get this warning. 
crypto.lib(err.c.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info

First can someone explain what this means.

I used sample vcxproj provided by grpc and it works fine. but when I include it in existing project it gives me above warning.